# How to aggregate over multiple fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Dango model `Trade` that store trades information for several markets. The objects are timestamped at every 5 minutes and I need to aggregate them by `market` and by `datetime`.

What is the best solution to do that with performance in mind ?

As you can see below, I could extract a list of the desired timestamps, iterate and aggregate data but I'm afraid it's not the most efficient solution.

```
class Trade(TimestampedModel):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    trades = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

This is my code:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

# Time order object 
qs = Trade.objects.all().order_by("-datetime")

# Extract unique timestamps
dts = qs.values_list("datetime", flat=True).distinct()

for dt in dts:

    cum_a = qs.filter(datetime=dt).aggregate(num_a=Sum('amount'))['num_a']
    cum_t = qs.filter(datetime=dt).aggregate(num_t=Sum('trades'))['num_t']
    avg_p = qs.filter(datetime=dt).aggregate(avg_p=Avg('price'))['avg_p']
    ....
    # Store aggregated data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:)

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

qs = Trade.objects.values('datetime').order_by('datetime').annotate(
    cum_a=Sum('amount'), 
    cum_t=Sum('trades'), 
    avg_p=Avg('price')
)
```

You iterate like that:

```
for row in qs:
    print(row["datetime"], row["cum_a"], row["cum_t"], row["avg_p"])
```

On SQL side you are grouping by `datetime` and running aggregation for each group.

```
SELECT "datetime", SUM("amount") AS "cum_a", SUM("trades") AS "cum_t", AVG("price") AS "avg_p"
FROM "Trade"
GROUP BY "datetime"
ORDER BY "datetime"
```

if you want to group by market too:

```
qs = Trade.objects.values('datetime', 'market').order_by('datetime', 'market') \
              .annotate(
                  cum_a=Sum('amount'), 
                  cum_t=Sum('trades'), 
                  avg_p=Avg('price')
              )

for row in qs:
    print(row["datetime"], row["market"], row["cum_a"], row["cum_t"], row["avg_p"])
```

Comment: @Florent does it make sence?

Comment: Hi, yes but I think I badly formulate my question because what I need is to aggregate by datetime, not datetime AND market. The answer is the same, thanks

Comment: I don't get it:). You want to aggragate by `datetime` and `market`. Yes?:) @Florent

Comment: Yes, but if I aggregate only by datetime it's the same no ?

Comment: Amm, it's a little different I guess. You can try to change this part: `values('datetime')` to `values('datetime', 'market')`. And check result of query. It means you are grouping by two columns simultaneously: `datetime` and `market`. @Florent

Comment: @Florent updated answer. Added version with market grouping.

Comment: Indeed, when I did with `values('datetime', 'market')` it returns the same amount of objects I have in the queryset. So it aggregates nothing in the end. I think the correct formulation is to aggregate only by datetime